# How to redefine JavaScript classes, in the console?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm fairly new to JS classes, and am doing mostly back-end work.

I was playing around with the new JS classes and so I started going through the examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

I went to the chrome (chromium) developer tools console and I wrote the Polygon class:

```js
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

Then I wanted to redefine the class, according to the example containing the methods, so I wrote:

```js
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  
  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

This raises an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Polygon' has already been declared(…)`

Now I understand there's a new scoping in ES6, and that classes automatically use the new scoping and so on... but really, how do I redefine my class?

Comment: So when you wrote that second part, you got an error?

Comment: I'm not following. Are you trying to have two classes named `Polygon` but one defined with a third property and method?

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this: `var Polygon = <my class>; Polygon = <redefine the class>`. I'm trying to redefine the class, which means I want to forget the old definition, and use the new one.

Comment: You should be able to do `Polygon = class { ... }` to reassign the class.

Comment: Wheres the problem? As classes are in fact functions in javascript, you can do var polygon =class {}; polygon = class {new stuff};

Comment: I guess the question is why would you do this? When you write JavaScript programs you shouldn't be altering class definitions at runtime unless you want to spend all your time tracking down bugs.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yup, that did it! So apparently I can't "erase" a variable which points to a class, if it was defined with the new class syntax. I can however make that variable point to something else.... like the value of a class expression.

Comment: Correct. `class Foo {}` is exactly like `let Foo = class Foo {};` so you can reassign `Foo` if you want, but you can't do a second declaration because you can't `let`-declare the same thing twice.

Comment: If you wanna erase sth, use "extend" instead

Comment: @Stephen as stated in the title, and in the question: I would do this because I'm following a tutorial, where they show multiple versions of the same class. I don't want to have to close the tab, and open a different one, just so I can test another feature of the class. I don't want to program like that, I just want to test stuff out. Please read the title/ question before posting.

Comment: @Jonasw The problem is that after I defined a class, with the syntax that I have shown, I can't do it again. I understand that this wouldn't work in a file, and for the right reasons. However in the console I don't want to have to close the tab, close the browser or restart the computer (exaggerating of course) just so that I can test new features of classes, step by step.

Comment: Yeah, but why dont you simply create a class A and if you wanna change sth simply do B extends A { changes }; ...

Comment: @Jonasw because I don't want to compromise my original idea. I refused to think it's not possible. Of course, by now, I know a good answer - which is just using a class expression instead of a statement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

None of the answers provide a solution without changing original code... So here is refined solution.

If in code you have something like this:

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

Then this means you've created a `let` variable named `Polygon`. You cannot redeclare `Polygon`, but you can reassign it.

So if you need to experiment in e.g. JS console just do:

```
Polygon = class {
  //... new stuff here
}
```

This will replace the original class but will not violate `let` restrictions.

You can try this out by pasting above code in the console, and then try `new Polygon(1,2)`.

Answer (score 6):

Block scope declarations (`let`, `const`, `class`) cannot be redeclared.

[Class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) and `var` can be used to re-use and re-declare variables in console:

```
var Polygon = class Polygon  { ... };
new Polygon();
var Polygon = class Polygon  { ... };
new Polygon();
```

Comment: My problem is that I have already used a class declaration.... So after doing that, I can simply reuse the variable name, but not use the name in another declaration. That means `class Polygon{}; ... Polygon = (class Polygon {})` works.

Comment: Just reload window and use `var` every time when pollution of console scope may be undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit) of Chrome, and although I can open up the console and declare a new class, I can't redefine a class (you'll get the error: `VM272:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Thing' has already been declared`, since I tried to redefine my class `Thing`).

If you simply want to add methods onto the class later, you can add them to the class's `prototype`:

```
Polygon.prototype.area = function() {
  // do some stuff
}
```

In that case, however, it won't be a `getter` method like in your example.

**Edit**

To get around the syntax error, if you just reassign a class as a variable, it should do what you want:

```
// in your original code

var Polygon = class{}

// in the console

var Polygon = class {
  // with new stuff
}
```

Comment: I want real methods.... I want to just forget the old definition, and have a new one.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean they are "real" methods. A class uses JavaScript prototypes under the hood.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean see my edit, you should just be able to use variable re-assignment to accomplish what you want

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. yes I just opened up my Chrome console and tried it and it works fine (note that my answer specifically mentions Chrome as the browser I'm using, and I haven't tried it on ff)

Comment: Same error, but if you omit the `var` then it works.

Comment: @JoshBeam Keep in mind: 1. Using `.prototype.X` creates enumerable properties, rather than non-enumerable like normal class syntax. 2. You cannot use `super` in methods added the way you are proposing. 3. You could make it a getter if you used `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: Your real problem is you're trying to use your browser console as a sandbox environment for testing. If you really have to do that simply refresh whatever page your on, otherwise use a sandbox like jsFiddle. in the real world you're not going to declare a class twice anyway.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. makes total sense and I agree with you 100%, but that doesn't answer the OP's question :P

Comment: that's why it's a comment ;)

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. The thing is, as per my disclaimer, I come from Python. I expect to be able to redefine things. I still think a console should allow you to do that, giving a warning. The fact that JavaScript was far too permissive as a language probably guided its development towards being very restrictive - too restrictive. That's why I think this is unexpected behavior, so I don't think that what I'm trying to achieve is unusual, but rather the console's behavior. Interestingly though, Ruby has a behavior exactly as I described to be desired. The console just warns on redefinition.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean - I disagree. I do full stack and work with a handful of languages and JS is by far the most syntactically flexible. There are dozens of ways to build classes and similar constructs, the one you happen to be using (which is still pretty new and [very poorly supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)) doesn't have that functionality. there are several other ways that do.

Answer (score -2):

Nice,

So now all of my class files begin like this:

```js
if(typeof(someClass)== undefined){
  class someClass{}
}
someClass= class{
  constructor(){
    console.log(typeof(someClass));
  }
}
const newobject= new someClass();
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Please add how exactly this solves the problem.