# Redeclaring a JavaScript class in a webconsole

Tags: javascript, browser, console

Say, one declares a class in a browser webconsole. After which, one changes the class. And now, one declares the new class definition under the same class name.

This will trigger the error below:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'ClassName' has already been declared
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Minimal working example: invoking this definition after the first time will reproduce the error;

```
class ClassName{
    \\ class content ...
}
```

How can this be circumvented?

Comment: Post more data about your code!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redefine JavaScript (NOT CSS) classes, in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471017/how-to-redefine-javascript-not-css-classes-in-the-console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reload the page where you have actually used the browser console then it will clear the console data together with the class `ClassName`. And you can use that again without the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'ClassName' has already been declared
>       at :1:1

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use of `const` in this case? Isn't the class definition I gave an object declaration? What *variable* are you referring to?

Comment: Yes, that is clear. I think what you meant previously with *variable* is that I should declare the *class definition* as a variable, like mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40471217/3646263): `var ClassName = class _ClassName{ \\ class content};` so I can change `_ClassName` as I please (without reloading the page).

Comment: @MusséRedi yes that what I meant but we usually don't use that syntax so you can simply reload the page. As simple as that :)