# Javascript - How to change the parent class of a class?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

Let's say we have 3 classes

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C {}
```

Is there a possibility to make `B` extends `C` instead of `A` ?

So `new B() instanceof C` will be `true`.
And `new B() instanceof A` will be `false`.

Comment: dynamically? No

Comment: Cruel world :,(

Comment: why you want it named `B`? if it's not the same as `B`?

Comment: Would this solution work for you?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51411186/1438757

Comment: @appleapple I want to keep the class B as it is, with all its methods and properties. And if I do `new B() instanceof C`, it should be true. B became a C, and it's not an A anymore. I doesn't have any methods or properties from A.

Comment: @JustinHamilton I don't want to make a new class with he same name, or in a variable B. I want to change this `B` 's inheritance.

Comment: @Yairopro I don't get it. you want a *different type* with the *same name*. you probably doing something wrong.

Comment: and consider what happens if `B`'s anything ever use something in `A`?

Comment: Any new instance of B won't be able to use anything from A anymore.

Comment: Certainly everything is possible, but what is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Why can you not just write `extends C` in the first place?

Comment: Do you want to change the complete `B` class, or individual instances of `B`?

Comment: I want to change the B class. Not instances that have already been or will be created.

Comment: Sounds like inheritance done inverted. You want both B of A and B of C share the B's functionality. So make A extends B and C extends B.

Comment: @VladimirM No I don't want B to inherits from A anymore. Only from C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
B.prototype.__proto__ = C.prototype
```

That's seems to be the correct answer.
But still **[it shouldn't be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)**.

Here's the demo

```js
class A {
  f(){
    console.log("I am a A")
  }
}

class B extends A {}

class C {
  f(){
    console.log("I am a C")
  }
}

// ----- test B -----
new B().f() // "I am a A";
console.log("B is an A: " + (new B instanceof A));
console.log("B is an C: " + (new B instanceof C));



// ------- CHANGE ------
console.log("Changing B's parent class to C !");
B.prototype.__proto__ = C.prototype;


// ------- retest -------
new B().f() // "I am a C";
console.log("B is an A: " + (new B instanceof A));
console.log("B is an C: " + (new B instanceof C));
```

Comment: This is a hack and you shouldn't do it because it could break without warning. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: @Lennholm Tanks a lot for the warning. Still this is the correct solution. I will add your warning to the answer.