# multiple class extensions with built-in classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, inheritance, mixins

I've been looking at mixins in typescript and wonder how I could implement my problem.
I have four classes:

```
AudioNode (native)
CustomAudioNode ( custom )
GainNode ( native )
CustomGainNode ( custom )
```

I would like to achieve this inheritance:

- 1 `CustomAudioNode` extends `AudioNode`.
- 2 `GainNode` extends `CustomAudioNode`.
- 3 `CustomGainNode` extends `GainNode` or `[GainNode,CustomAudioNode]`.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you should be modifying native objects.

Comment: This is not a TypeScript question either. It's more of a JavaScript problem if you want to touch native prototypes.

Comment: @vr it is also a typescript problem as the mixin or inherithance system needs to be compliant with typescript.I've trie earlier a [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61860802/1713208) and typescript compilatio failed.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes but you're also asking to change a *native class* to extend a *custom class*.

Comment: @vr. that's true, it's both a typescript and javascript problem.Any ideas?

Comment: @vr. Even though you think I shouldn't modify a native object I still don't know what could be a workaround?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to change a native class's parent class... The very best you could do is copy the prototype of the new parent class to the native class/native parent class.

Comment: @vr. if you have code I'll be glad to try.Thanks.

Comment: You could try this but it's really  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823432/javascript-how-to-change-the-parent-class-of-a-class

Comment: @vr. yes I can't take the risk to break my application

Comment: Having probably read the Web Audio API documentation, what remains unclear about the approaches one could e.g. implement a `CustomAudioNode`? And why, also after having read the docs, would one want to implement a `GainNode` type which extends `CustomAudioNode`. What would have both abstraction in common? The OP also might think about sharing some of the code the OP already came up with.

Comment: @PeterSeliger `GainNode`inherits from `AudioNode` some I'm adding extra layers in beween. THe reason for that is just I need members and method inheritance when creating my custom componenent as I'm adding a wrapper around some WebAudio API classes.Hope it's clear enough.Thanks

Comment: In order to come up with some/one approach/es of how to implement the custom versions of `AudioNoe`/`GainNode` one needs to know what each type is expected to feature in addition to what each of the original implementation is already capable of. This very much would help with choosing the best fitting composition/inheritance techniques/patterns. The OP again is asked to come up with some (pseudo) code in order to get a better understanding of the entire matter.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to straightforwardly build a relationship like the one the OP is looking for, which involves both native `AudioNode` and native `GainNode`, each with another custom implementation (`CustomAudioNode` and `CustomGainNode`) where ...

> 1. `CustomAudioNode` extends `AudioNode`.
> 2. `GainNode` extends `CustomAudioNode`.
> 3. `CustomGainNode` extends `GainNode` or `[GainNode,CustomAudioNode]`.

This is due to ...

- [`GainNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode) already extends `AudioNode`.
- [`AudioNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode) neither can be extended nor can it be wrapped in any meaningful way (thus, it is going to remain untouched).

But what can be done instead is ...

- providing any additional behavior which is related to `AudioNode` as mixin, preferably implemented as function based mixin.

This is, one provides a very clean code base which now involves just a `CustomGainNode` which extends the native counterpart and provides custom gain node behavior, whereas custom audio node behavior gets implemented separately, but applied at any custom gain node's construction/instantiation time.

````js
// the pure custom audio node specific functionality.

function customAudioNodeBahavior01() {
  // `this` refers to the current `CustomGainNode` instance
  //  which too is an instance of `GainNode` and `AudioNode`.
}
function customAudioNodeBahavior02() {
  // `this` refers to the current `CustomGainNode` instance
  //  which too is an instance of `GainNode` and `AudioNode`.
}

// the function based mixin.
function withCustomAudioNodeBahavior() {
  Object.assign(this, {
    customAudioNodeBahavior01,
    customAudioNodeBahavior02,
  });
}

// the custom gain node subclass/subtype.
class CustomGainNode extends GainNode {
  constructor(...args) {

    // - `args` are always ...
    //   `context`and `options`
    //   ... like with ...
    //   ```
    //   constructor(context, options) {
    //     super(context, options);
    //     // ...
    //   }
    //   ```

    // the inheritance part.
    super(...args);

    // the mixin based composition part.
    withCustomAudioNodeBahavior.call(this);

    // - implementing further custom gain node
    //   specific behavior.
  }
}
````

**Note**

In order to comply with the [***Web Audio Api***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), the OP might think about implementing the pendant of the [`BaseAudioContext.createGain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createGain) factory method ... something like `BaseAudioContext.createCustomGain`.

Comment: I appreciate you time and effort for answering me.I think you've misunderstood something or maybe I'm wrong, I've said that `CustomAudioNode` is a wrapper of `AudioNode` which works.

Comment: In fact I found a solution. I create a `CustomAudioNode` that is extended by `AudioNode` and finally implement a `CustomGainNode` that creates a `GainNode` instance inside the constructor.This should be sufficient for my needs.Thanks again.

Comment: _"In fact I found a solution"_ ... and you're invited to share it here, taking the risk of getting voted in either way. ... _"I create a `CustomAudioNode` that is extended by `AudioNode`"_ ... I 'd really like to see exactly this part of your code.

Comment: `class CustomAudioNode extends AudioNode {...`

Comment: _"I've said that CustomAudioNode is a wrapper of AudioNode which works"_ ... which probably is tons of code which just implements forwarding functionality for every method defined by the `AudiNode` interface. Why not giving the specialized audio node related mixin approach a chance?

Comment: _"`class CustomAudioNode extends AudioNode {. `"_ ... no more the constructor part (with/without super call) _**and especially how one does create an instance of `CustomAudioNode`**_ (with/without `new` and the passed arguments).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to tell here (I'm using `extends` not using `implements`).But after reflection and due to my structure I probably simplify my whole logic to `CustomGainNode extends CustomAudioNode`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252967/discussion-between-jsmith-and-peter-seliger).